# Existence of Monotone Sequence of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a measurable space with measurable sets $\Sigma$ and denote the space of simple functions by:$$\mathcal{S}:=\{s:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:s=\sum_{k=1}^K s_k\chi_{A_k},s_k\in\mathbb{R},A_k\in\Sigma,K\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

Consider a measurable function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}_+$. Then:
$$\exists s_n\in\mathcal{S}:s_n(\omega)\to f(\omega),\omega\in\Omega\implies\exists s_n\in\mathcal{S}:s_n(\omega)\uparrow f(\omega),\omega\in\Omega$$

Does this fail if the function were not necessarily measurable?

The problem I encounter here is that the construction of the monotone sequence exploits the measurability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is a pointwise limit of $s_n$'s then it is measurable so your implication is true for all functions.

Comment: The original poster said that the reason the simple functions are measurable is because to construct them, you use the fact that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: @user46944: I was confused there but in fact it is quite simple: The pointwise limit of a measurable sequence is measurable and a measurable function is pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions.